# Hibernate order Entity results by an ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a model that looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tSomething")
public class Something {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "tSomething_units")
    private List<String> units = new ArrayList<>();

    // snip getters/setters
}
```

I can retreive a List of Something ordered by `name` by doing:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MinutesCode.class);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
```

And everything comes out as expected:

```
5, Alice, CC
1, Bob, AA, AB, CC
4, Carol, AB
2, Dave, DD, AB
```

How do I order them by the `units` so that they come out like this:

```
1, Bob, AA, AB, CC
4, Carol, AB
5, Alice, CC
2, Dave, DD, AB
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class, call it `MyCriteria`, that implements the `Criteria` interface and has a constructor that takes another `Criteria` as an input parameter. This would change your code to look like this:

```
Criteria criteria = new MyCriteria(session.createCriteria(MinutesCode.class));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
List results = criteria.list();
```

`MyCriteria` would pass incoming method calls on to the wrapped `Criteria`. However the `list()` method would get the results from the wrapped `Criteria` and reorder the results according to your application's needs before returning them.

I am unaware of anything in the `Criteria` api that supports what you are looking for directly.